# Testing with UIKit and Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, uikit, jestjs

I have the following code in an angular component where `declare const UIkit: any;` is at the top of the file with the other imports.

When I run my tests with jest, I get the following error: `ReferenceError: UIkit is not defined` when the component is being created via the `TestBed`

Just wondering how I can point to the `UIkit` library during tests such that it doesn't fail.

```
declare const UIkit: any;

...

  ngOnInit() {
    UIkit.util.on('.sortables', 'moved', (item) => {
      // get order of blocks
      const blocks = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.sortable'));
      const newPositions = blocks.slice(0, blocks.length - 1).map(block => {
        return block.getAttribute('data-index');
      });

      // reorder document.blocks to match new order
      const newlyOrderedBlocks = [];
      newPositions.forEach(index => {
        newlyOrderedBlocks.push(this.document.blocks[index]);
      });
      this.document.blocks = newlyOrderedBlocks;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working for me was removing the global var declaration and declaring it as a module.

Install `@types/uikit`

**uikit.ts**

```
declare module 'uikit';
```

**component.ts**

```
import * as UIkit from 'uikit';

...

  ngOnInit() {
    UIkit.util.on('.sortables', 'moved', (item) => {
      // get order of blocks
      const blocks = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.sortable'));
      const newPositions = blocks.slice(0, blocks.length - 1).map(block => {
        return block.getAttribute('data-index');
      });

      // reorder document.blocks to match new order
      const newlyOrderedBlocks = [];
      newPositions.forEach(index => {
        newlyOrderedBlocks.push(this.document.blocks[index]);
      });
      this.document.blocks = newlyOrderedBlocks;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Where does the uikit.ts file go to declare it as a module?